# External Code chunks in knitr with LaTeX

Tags: r, tex, knitr

I have been unable to get external code chunks to work in knitr from a LaTeX (*.Rtex) document.

foo.R contains:

```
## @knitr foo
#
tx <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)
ty <- cos(tx*3.0)
plot(tx,ty,pch=20,col='blue')
seq(3)
```

The test1.Rtex document contains:

```
%% read_chunk('Code/foo.R')
% 
%%

%% begin.rcode foo, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE, eval=TRUE
%% end.rcode
```

knit('test1.Rtex') yields:

```
chunk "foo" is empty or set not to be evaluated
```

I have a copy of the knitr git repository.  Modifying this code with `cat(sprint())` statements there is no evidence of `read_chunk()` being used in LaTeX code.

Comment: So your call to read_chunk isn't inside one a begin.rcode/end.rcode chunk?